# find out on something

Tags: prepositional-phrases, parsing

Example:

> French archaeologist Francois Bordes interpreted variations in stone tool remains as evidence of different groups of people who existed in the past. American archaeologist Lewis Binford, however, believed these variations reflected different activities. Who was right? **Find out** in this lecture **on the way** scientists interpret the archaeological record.

Is it correct to say it like that? I know you can say *find out the way scientists interpret the archaeological record*, which is perfect English, but *find out on something* sounds grammatically, kind of, strange. What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"On the way" in this sentence modifies "lecture", not "find out". Compare

- Attend the lecture on the way scientists interpret the archaeological record.
- Find out how scientists interpret the archaeological record.

Answer (score 0):

"On" simply means "about" in this context. As in [The Feynman Lectures on Physics](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/).